# Can I get an exception when setting a NSObject to BOOL property?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I receive a crash log

```
-[__NSCFConstantString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8224d0
```

so I checked the code and find it's caused by

```
[self setValue:value forKeyPath:key];
```

but I can't reappear this crash when I set a NSString to a BOOL property manually.

Does it really cause crash?

Now I will check the type before setting the property,but I don't know if I have fixed this issue.

Updated the code:

```
-(instancetype)initWithDic:(NSDictionary *)dic
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        if(![dic isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])   
            return self;

        //now I do sth,funtion "propertyOfClass" will not return the BOOL-type properties

        NSArray *properties = [Utils propertyOfClass:[self class]];

        for(NSString *key in properties)
        {
            NSString *value = GET_STRING(dic[key]);

            if (![value isEqualToString:@""]) {
                [self setValue:value forKeyPath:key];
            }
        }

    }

    return self;
}
```

And now I'm trying to reappear this crash with the code

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL propertyA;
@end

 ClassA *a = [ClassA new];

 [a setValue:@"xx" forKey:@"propertyA"];
 [a setValue:@"" forKeyPath:@"propertyA"];
```

Comment: It's a very confusing question, but it is a real crash, yes and will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Yes.

When calling `[NSObject setValue:forKeyPath:]` you need to make sure the type of the object `value` matches the type for the property you defined.

Note that in your case the crash seems to be that you're calling a method on an object that doesn't know of that method. That's what "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8224d0". I think the `key` you're passing isn't an NSString.

Comment: `NSString` doesn't have a `charValue` method.  The problem is that the message *is* being sent to a string.

Comment: I'm sure that both `key` and `value` are `NSString` , but it really makes me confused that why I cannot reappear the crash :(

Comment: What's the code you're trying to reproduce the crash?

Comment: I'm trying to setting the properties of some object from json string, but there's some BOOL-type properties, and these values do not come from the json. The code is updated in my question. Now I change the code so the `propertyOfClass` will not return the property name which is BOOL-type